# Python class methods overloading

Tags: python, oop

How can I overload class methods?
I failed with:

```
class D(object):
    def create(self):
        foo = 100
        bar = 'squirrels'
        baz = 'I have %d insane %s in my head.' % (foo, bar)
        return baz     

class C(D):
    def create(self):
        super(C, self).create()
        baz = 'I have %s cute %s in my yard.' % (self.foo, self.bar)

C().create()
```

Traceback was:

```
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tried to use local variables as class attributes. Try to do the following changes:

```
class D(object):
    def create(self):
        self.foo = 100
        self.bar = 'squirrels'
        baz = 'I have %d insane %s in my head.' % (self.foo, self.bar)
        return baz

class C(D):
    def create(self):
        super(C, self).create()
        print self.foo
        self.baz = 'I have %s cute %s in my yard.' % (self.foo, self.bar)

C().create()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `D.create` you do not set the variables on `self`, which means the variable `foo` is a local variable of that function.

```
class D(object):
    def create(self):
        self.foo = 100
        self.bar = 'squirrels'
        self.baz = 'I have %d insane %s in my head.' % (self.foo, self.bar)
        return self.baz
```

Comment: `create()` returns no `D` resp. `C` object, but a string. So `__init__` would probably not lead to somewhere...